# Jupyter notebook python version different from environment python version

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I wanted to run jupyter notebook with python: 3.7.10 so I created a virtual env and activated it using anaconda. Then when I run Jupyter notebook, it still uses python 3.8.8. How can I change the python version used by jupyter notebook?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: What command did you use to create the environment?  Is your base installation using 3.8.8?

Comment: I used conda conda create -n myenv python=3.7. Yes, my base installation is 3.8.8.

Answer (score 1):

You have probably typed jupyter notebook in the command prompt and it opened.
Actually jupyter and notebook are two modules that you need to install on your virtual environment. So that you can leverage jupyter notebook from that environment.
In your case since you didn't had them it started from the one having.

Now the way I suggest to start jupyter from a particular environment is from the navigator itself as shown in the figure below.

[image: Anaconda]

Select your environment and then install and launch jupyter notebook.

If it doesn't work you can try integrating conda with jupyter notebook and run your environment directly from jupyter notebook using the package nb_conda. Check this 4 min video [youtu.be/Ro9l0eapoJU](https://youtu.be/Ro9l0eapoJU) for the process.

Comment: I tried doing this but the jupyter notebook still does not use the python version of the environment.

Comment: You can try integrating  conda with jupyter notebook and run your environment directly using the package nb_conda. Check this 4 min video https://youtu.be/Ro9l0eapoJU for the process. Hopefully this will resolve your issue @vedjain .